# Dragon Age: Inquisition PC with Game-pad controls

Tags: pc, controllers, dragon-age-inquisition

I started playing Dragon Age Inquisition on my PC yesterday (21 November 2014) when it was released. After about 4 hours of not enjoying the keyboard/mouse interface, I decided to give my gamepad a try. This works much better for me.

One huge problem I have though, is that I cannot figure out how to open the quest map while using the gamepad. With the keyboard configuration this is done by hitting the <kbd>M</kbd> key. The manual also is no help trying to figure this out:

[image]

The funniest thing for me is: I can't find any references anywhere online that indicates that anybody else is having issues trying to open the quest map with a gamepad. I personally feel I cannot play the game without the map, as I'd be running around blind looking for quest locations. Naturally, I tried getting to the map from other windows that you are able to open, but to no avail. Is this perhaps something that could get patched (hopefully in the near future)?

Comment: What type of gamepad are you using? Wired Xbox 360?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, this is quite embarrassing. I read further in the manual:
[image]

and noticed that the quest map does indeed appear in the hero menu, in the center. I was looking for it on the outside points of the star.

Comment: Don't worry, I did the same thing. :) I started off using a gamepad though... and I thought it was quite odd the game didn't have a "quest map" or overview map. I actually found it by accident about 5 hours in.

Answer (score 1):

The console versions would pop up the quest map if you pressed left on the d-pad. Not sure why you can't when using a controller on the PC but as you've figured out, it's in the hero menu through the start button.